# Auto renaming a download?

Tags: html, download

I have a webpage with a bunch of download links and a name before each download link, the format of the webpage looks like this:

> File One's name
>
> *direct download link here*
>
> File Two's name
>
> *direct download link here*

and so on.

Is it possible to write a program so it mass downloads all the links on the page with each one being named the names above their respective link? What can I use in order to write something that can this?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend writing a scraper in python using the [scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) framework.

Using this framework you will be able to extract all of the links from the page and pass them to a [media pipeline in scrapy](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html), this media pipeline will allow you to download and save the files with custom names (For example the name above the link).

It's a lot to take in if you haven't programmed, used python or used scrapy before but there are loads of [tutorials](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html) out there to help you.

Good luck!!

Answer (score 0):

You can initialise a variable for Name of your download file at first.

```
$filename = "XYZ";//File Name
```

And at the download function you can call that variable name so that it will be the name of your downloaded file.

```
//header info for browser
    header("Content-Type: application/xls");    
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.xls");  
    header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
    header("Expires: 0");
```

In this the downloaded file will be named as XYZ with extension .xls